# Mockito spy - when calling inner class method not spying method in spy object

Tags: java, android, mockito

I have class with inner class as following:

```
public class ClassWithInnerObject {

  private final InnerObject innerObject;

  public ClassWithInnerObject() {
    innerObject = new InnerObject();
  }

  public void callInnerObjectMethod() {
    innerObject.outerFunc();
  }

  public void outerFunc() {
    innerFunc();
  }

  public void innerFunc() {
    Log.d("XXX", "innerFunc: called");
  }

  public class InnerObject {
    public void outerFunc() {
      innerFunc();
    }
  }
}
```

And the mockito test is looking as following:
build.gradle:

```
  androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

  androidTestCompile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.4'
  androidTestCompile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.4'
  androidTestCompile 'com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:1.4'
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class) public class SpyVerifyTest {

  @Test public void myInnerTestWorking() {
    ClassWithInnerObject p = new ClassWithInnerObject();
    ClassWithInnerObject spy = Mockito.spy(p);
    spy.outerFunc();
    verify(spy, times(1)).innerFunc();
  }


  @Test public void myInnerTestNotWorking() {
    ClassWithInnerObject p = new ClassWithInnerObject();
    ClassWithInnerObject spy = Mockito.spy(p);
    spy.callInnerObjectMethod();
    verify(spy, times(1)).innerFunc();
  }

}
```

The first test is working as expected.
The second one the `innerFunc` is never detected as "invoked", although in the log I see it is.What is wrong? :)

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question already asked is a different case:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22644040/5627827

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is wrong?

Well, the problem here is quite subtle, when you call `Mockito.spy(p)`, `mockito` creates behind the scene some kind of decorator over your instance of `ClassWithInnerObject` allowing to monitor all methods calls on your instance. Thanks to that, you can check how many times a given method has been called **but on the decorator only** not on your instance. And here, when you use an inner class, it calls `innerFunc()` on your instance of `ClassWithInnerObject` not on the decorator so for `Mockito` `innerFunc()` **has not been called**.

Answer (score 0):

You can Fix that by using "ClassWithInnerObject.this." in inner class.

```
public class InnerObject {
  public void outerFunc() {
    ClassWithInnerObject.this.innerFunc();
  }
}
```