# Mockito verify not working on a spied object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to use verify in a unit test to verify a method gets called on an object that is spied. I can verify the method is actually being called via a log statement and stepping through the code with a debugger. yet a verify(Object,1).method() call reports "Wanted but not invoked:" Also with the assertion uncommented mockTransferService.getCurrentTask() is returning null while again I can verify with the debugger that it is getting set. 
Test code is shown below

```
 @Test
    public void testInitialPermitGranted() throws Exception {
        Config mockConfig = mock(Config.class);
        doReturn(path).when(mockConfig).getRequiredStringProperty(Config.WORK_DIR);
        mockTransferService = spy(new TransferServiceImpl(mockServiceConnection, mockConfig,
                Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()));
        doReturn(true).when(mockTransferService).doStartTransfer(any());
        mockTransferService.enqueueTransfer(mockTransferTask);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        //Assert.assertEquals(mockTransferTask, mockTransferService.getCurrentTask());
        verify(mockTransferService,times(1)).startTransfer(any());
    }
}
```

Method that is being tested is shown below

```
@Override
    public boolean startTransfer(TransferTask transferTask) {
        LOG.debug("StartTransferCalled");
        setCurrentTask(transferTask);
        return doStartTransfer(transferTask);
    }
```

I'm pretty new to mockito and obviously I am missing something.

Comment: Can you show to which class the method startTransfer belongs?  And, please explain your test code a bit more: From which part of the test code do you expect the method startTransfer to be called?  It does not seem to be called directly.

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616976/mockito-spy-when-calling-inner-class-method-not-spying-method-in-spy-object. The method was called from an inner class that handles the enqueued task.